# Switch mobile app to use a new Google OAuth client ID

Tags: ios, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

We're using an OAuth 2.0 client ID for an iOS Application that was generated under a Google Developers account that is no longer available to us.

We would like to change to a new client ID, as created under "APIs & auth/Credentials" in the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com).

We would like to do this in a way that has as little impact as possible on the users of our iOS application.

What are the options for migrating the client ID?  Can we do this without changing the name of the folder that we currently write documents into?

What we're looking at doing is:

1. create a new folder with a different name
2. retrieve the documents from the old folder using the old ID
3. write the documents into the new folder using the new ID
4. delete (or rename) the old folder using the old ID
5. rename the new folder to be the preferred name.

I'm looking for confirmation that this is the best way to do this, or (preferably) ideas for a simpler approach.

Thanks!